# ASP.net -2147467259 (0x80004005) error

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to debug some legacy asp.net 1.1 code. I have moved the app to my local machine to debug. When I try to load any aspx page I get the following error. 
-2147467259 (0x80004005)

That's all that's on the page. Anybody have a clue where I should start to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turned out to be a problem with the asp.net 1.1 install.

To debug it I created a new blank page and still got the error. Created a new application with a hello world type form same error.

**Solution:** "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_regiis.exe" -i

Answer (score 1):

You gotta love all these error messages with relatively vague text, tons of solutions already cropping up.

Research I dug into really quick indicated that something good have gone wacky with the .NET 2.0 Framework after getting the 1.1 stuff on your machine. They recommended to do a repair/reinstall of the 2.0 Framework and reboot the machine. That solved their woes.

Just go down the list and one of us will have the right answer. 8^D It doesn't help when MS sends you generic errors. 8^D

Comment: Usually it includes some vague text that helps search the problem though. This one was just a number.

Comment: <smiles/> No worries. I've seen both the descriptive, and the non-descriptive errors in my day. It's just hard to get a solid answer when the only error message you have is just numbers. That's all. 8^D

Comment: Sidenote: I meant no ill will towards the question itself, I think it's perfectly legit. It is just the general scenario we typically get to debug as developers.

Comment: The ones with a little bit of text are easier to search. -2147467259 returns nothing in a search.

Comment: Yeah, I had to put a "" around the Google search since Google reads that as "dont' give me results with 2147467259 in it". Glad you found the solution.

Comment: Oh yeah, don't forget to mark your own solution as the answer. That's legit and will help "close" the issue. Sounds weird, but the green boxes are rather helpful here.

Comment: It won't let me do it for 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an "Access is denied" error, if you look up that error code in Windows anyway, where I'd check to see that the "Temporary ASP.Net Files" are being generated and that the identity used to compile the code can read the source files.

Comment: Access denied (5) as an HRESULT would be (IIRC) 0x80008005 (note 8 == FACILITY_WINDOWS rather than 4 which is FACILITY_ITF).

Answer (score 0):

0x80004005 is the COM error code E_FAIL "Unspecified error". So some COM method call failed.

Time to find a re-create and then use divide and conquer to find where this is happening.

It could easily be in non-managed code, so enable native debugging and check you have MS' symbol server configured.

Answer (score -1):

That looks like a COM error to me. It would help if you provided more detail about what you are doing when you get the error. Maybe post some code?

Usually where I see this is when connecting to a database. When you moved your application, did you change your database connection string(s) appropriately?

Also, when you set up IIS on your local server, did you [check the necessary permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa954062.aspx)?